# How can I programmaticaly copy text from notepad and paste it into specific textboxes in my vb net app?

Tags: vb.net, copy-paste

I am trying to make a program that can copy strings from notepad and paste it into specific text boxes in my windows form app.

For example, Lets say I have a text box with 5 different strings each one in a different line. So my program contains 5 text boxes.

I want with a press of a single button string from notepad line 1 goes to text box 1 , string from line 2 to textbox 2 etc...

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As UInteger = &H2
    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As UInteger = &H4

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
        'TextBox1.Text = e.Location.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        TextBox1.Text = MousePosition.ToString()
    End Sub

    Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dx As UInteger, ByVal dy As UInteger, ByVal dwData As UInteger, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

    Public Sub LeftClick()
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        Thread.Sleep(100) 'Wait required
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(40, 78)
        LeftClick()
        LeftClick()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        SendKeys.Send("^c")
        Me.BringToFront()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        TextBox2.Paste()
        'SendKeys.Send("^v")
        Thread.Sleep(300)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(41, 97)
        LeftClick()
        LeftClick()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        SendKeys.Send("^c")
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        Me.BringToFront()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        TextBox3.Paste()
        'SendKeys.Send("^v")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(32, 116)
        LeftClick()
        LeftClick()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        SendKeys.Send("^c")
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        Me.BringToFront()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        TextBox4.Paste()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(28, 133)
        LeftClick()
        LeftClick()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        SendKeys.Send("^c")
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        Me.BringToFront()
        TextBox5.Clear()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        TextBox5.Paste()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(23, 151)
        LeftClick()
        LeftClick()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        SendKeys.Send("^c")
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        Me.BringToFront()
        TextBox6.Clear()
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        TextBox6.Paste()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Button1.PerformClick()
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Button2.PerformClick()
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Button3.PerformClick()
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Button4.PerformClick()
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Button5.PerformClick()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()
        TextBox6.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I was trying something like that but doesn't work. If I press manually the buttons sometimes did the job but the most of them it will copy paste only the first string to all text boxes.

Comment: Quick search discovered [Read External Program Text Using VB.Net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asmabegam/external-program-text-read-using-VB-Net/)

Comment: There's no need for all that, just use the [GetText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.text.textpatternrange.gettext) method of the UI Automation [TextPattern.DocumentRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.textpattern.documentrange) property of a [TextPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.textpattern) object. You don't need to *click stuff* or anything else, just read a property value.

Comment: I suspect that the `Me.BringToFront()` is changing the focus from your Notepad to your program so that the later `SendKeys` are going to your own form instead of Notepad.  I would suggest that you 1) first do a Select-All (^a) in the Notepad so that your Copy (^c) gets *all* of the lines at once, then 2) skip the `Me.BringToFront()` and keyboard Paste (^v), but instead 3) get all of the text straight from the paste buffer into a VB string, then 4) parse it into a string array with `Split()` and finally 5) go through the array and assign each row to each `Textbox.Text`.

Comment: @Jimi, how do you apply that to an external app like Notepad?  I read the linked page but it didn't say anything about that.  Obviously, anything that gets rid of SendKeys is a good idea.

Comment: Actually  I use the notepad as an example. In fact i would like to take data (numbers) from another programm's window that i have no other access. These numbers are in a specific position so thats why i m using the new.point function

Comment: @RBarryYoung You can find the Notepad Window with `AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst()` , using `TreeScope.Children` and, e.g., an `AndCondition` set to `new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window),
new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Notepad")` (or, if you already have the Handle of the Window, with `AutomationElement.FromHandle()`), then get the `Edit` Control (with its class name, simply `"Edit"`), get the TextPattern of it and retrieve the text. -- If the OP is interested, I'll post it.

Comment: @Jimi  Wow, I always thought that the Automation namespace was just WPF internal stuff.  Will it work in a WinForms app?  If so, then I would be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, of course it can be used in WinForms (or C++/CLI, as exposed by .Net), the same way you can use, e.g., a BitmapSource: you just need to reference the assemblies (with the knowledge that referencing WPF assemblies, your WinForms app *automagically* becomes DpiAware, if it's not already). -- It appears that the OP is not trying to get text from Notepad, after all. UI Automation is relatively *precise*, so you need to know the Control Type or class name or Automation Id or a combination of any other property that can single out a specific Element (that supports Automation)...

Comment: @RBarryYoung [...] Of course, you can proceed by trial & error, get all the child Elelments of a Window, inspect the resulting collection, then determine the Type or Name (if any) or any other relevant detail of the one you're interested in and use this information to get it. Or use `Spy++` or `Inspect` to find the same information.

Comment: You can see clearly what is happening with my code to the video in the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2w8Sz37KOM   It works but i have to press two times the same button, otherwise it paste the previous copied string ... Why is that happening ?

Comment: @ΒασιληςΤακατουκας I have added an answer which is the best explanation I have for why this may be happening to you.  But really, SendKeys has just always been sketchy and unreliable because it it doesn't really implement any synchronization between the sending and receiving apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I have been using VB (30 years) the SendKeys functionality has been notoriously unreliable.  Although it has gotten better over the years, it's still pretty random.  Here's part of the warning from the current version (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=net-5.0):

> The SendKeys class is susceptible to timing issues, which some
> developers have had to work around. The updated implementation is
> still susceptible to timing issues, but is slightly faster and may
> require changes to the workarounds. The SendKeys class tries to use
> the previous implementation first, and if that fails, uses the new
> implementation. As a result, the SendKeys class may behave differently
> on different operating systems.

Specifically, timing and focus are problems, much of what is supposed to happen in response to a keystroke requires response and processing by the active application which can override the expected behavior, or even just take too long to decide *not* to override the builtin windows behavior.  My number one recommendation for all uses of SendKeys has always been: *Try to find any other way to do this without SendKeys*.  Two different ways are described/linked in the comments which you might consider.

If you decide to stick with SendKeys, then these are the only suggestions I can think if that *might* help:

1. Add another `Thread.Sleep` immediately after the (^c).
2. Send the (^c) twice with a wait in-between.  Or even have the code run the whole routine twice with a Sleep in-between (yes, I know how dumb this is).
3. Try using `SendKeys.SendWait` instead.
4. Try adding the following section to your App.config file:

   <appSettings>

   <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>

   </appSettings>

Note, there is some indication that (3) and (4) may not work together.  Try both ways and see.

Comment: sometimes  (^c) do nothing and when My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText comes i m getting the previous copied value not the last one ... Any suggestions please ?

Comment: @ΒασιληςΤακατουκας All of my suggestions are in my answer above or else in the comments to your question.